# Active se aplica a los elementos internos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Lo que sucede es que tengo algunos tabs de Bootstrap, por medio de un JS les estoy aplicando una clase para que se marquen cuanto estén desplegadas, el inconveniente es que tengo un tab dentro de otro y al desplegar el superior, me le aplica el active también a los internos, por favor me podrían ayudar a analizar la función ya que no encuentro como solucionar este problema, acá el código funcionando:

```js
// Activate collapse
(function() {

  $(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'show') {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });

}).call(this);
// End
```

```css
.panel-default {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading a {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.panel-default .panel-body {
  border: 0 !important;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-default .panel-body a {
  color: #707070;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.panel-default .panel-body a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .panel-default .panel-body ul {
    columns: 1;
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    -moz-columns: 1;
  }
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li ul {
  columns: 1;
  -webkit-columns: 1;
  -moz-columns: 1;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul.ul-columOne {
  columns: 1;
  -webkit-columns: 1;
  -moz-columns: 1;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.panel-default.active .panel-heading a {
  background-color: #C4D600;
  color: #005744;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  content: "-";
  float: right;
  color: #005744;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "+";
}

.siteMap h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Medium";
  color: #005744;
}

.siteMap h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Medium";
  color: #005744;
  margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

.siteMap p.legal {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Light";
}

.siteMap p.Light {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Light";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Viviendas -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-viviendas-mobile-tab">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile-tab" href="#collapseOne-viviendas-mobile-tab">
          VIVIENDAS
         </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne-viviendas-mobile-tab" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-viviendas-mobile">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseOne-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 1
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTwo-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 2
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseThree-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 3
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseFour-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 4
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseFive-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 5
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTSix-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 6
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTSix-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTSeven-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 7
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTSeven-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTEight-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 8
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTEight-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseNine-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 9
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseNine-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End viviendas -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Busca el selector:

```
.panel-default.active .panel-heading a
```

y cambialo por:

```
.panel-default.active>.panel-heading a
```

Es decir, agrega un `>` entre el selector padre e hijo, para indicar que solo afectara al primer descendiente directo y no los anidados o "nietos".

```js
// Activate collapse
(function() {

  $(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'show') {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });

}).call(this);
// End
```

```css
.panel-default {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading a {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.panel-default .panel-body {
  border: 0 !important;
  color: #707070;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-default .panel-body a {
  color: #707070;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.panel-default .panel-body a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .panel-default .panel-body ul {
    columns: 1;
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    -moz-columns: 1;
  }
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li ul {
  columns: 1;
  -webkit-columns: 1;
  -moz-columns: 1;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul li ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.panel-default .panel-body ul.ul-columOne {
  columns: 1;
  -webkit-columns: 1;
  -moz-columns: 1;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.panel-default.active>.panel-heading a {
  background-color: #C4D600;
  color: #005744;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Regular";
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  content: "-";
  float: right;
  color: #005744;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "+";
}

.siteMap h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Medium";
  color: #005744;
}

.siteMap h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Medium";
  color: #005744;
  margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

.siteMap p.legal {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Light";
}

.siteMap p.Light {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Mitr-Light";
}

.war{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Viviendas -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-viviendas-mobile-tab">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile-tab" href="#collapseOne-viviendas-mobile-tab">
          VIVIENDAS
         </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne-viviendas-mobile-tab" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-viviendas-mobile">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseOne-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 1
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTwo-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 2
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseThree-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 3
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseFour-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 4
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseFive-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 5
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTSix-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 6
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTSix-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTSeven-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 7
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTSeven-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseTEight-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 8
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTEight-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-viviendas-mobile" href="#collapseNine-viviendas-mobile">
                TEXTO 9
               </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseNine-viviendas-mobile" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End viviendas -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```